# How do I compile QT under LGPL for release on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-construction, qt4, dependencies

How do I compile Qt for free, on either MINGW, whilst statically compiling the mingw dll or Microsoft C++ express, not Studio? What dll's do I have to supply locally, on either options and how for QT and mingw/mc++ too have no external dependencies? I am compiling on an XP VM

I would prefer mingw, due to linux-windows compatibility and I what dlls do I need in the working directory for mingw compiled Qt program, to release, to a pc with no Qt or mingw installed.

Comment: [http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Support_for_Windows](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Support_for_Windows) ?

Answer (score 3):

`configure.exe -platform win32-msvc -opensource`

The main issue with VS-express is that the excellent vs-addin doesn't work so you need to add the moc step manually to new files and you can't import a .pro

If you can't use the plugin I would seriously look at Qt Creator